# rolling apply method with a numpy function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, rolling-computation

so I have a numpy function that returns a float.
I would like to see how the value changes over time to see its stabililty.
Hence I would like a rolling window with the function on a time series

Time series looks like

```
array([-9.51263882e-03, -2.81717483e-02,  9.43949087e-05, ...,
       -9.07504803e-03, -4.77400512e-03,  1.51740085e-03])
```

I am using the following function for rolling window

```
# Reshape a numpy array 'a' of shape (n, x) to form shape((n - window_size), window_size, x))
def rolling_window(a, window, step_size):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1 - step_size + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1] * step_size,)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

The function i am trying to calculate rolling is below:

```
def dist_range(x, y):
  return (np.max(np.abs(x - y), axis=1) - np.min(np.abs(x - y), axis=1)) / (np.max(np.abs(x - y), axis=1) + np.min(np.abs(x - y), axis=1))

##### RangeEn-B (mSampEn)
def RangeEn_B(x, emb_dim=2, tolerance=.1, dist=dist_range):

    n = np.shape(x)
    n = np.max(n)

    tVecs = np.zeros((n - emb_dim, emb_dim + 1))
    for i in range(tVecs.shape[0]):
        tVecs[i, :] = x[i:i + tVecs.shape[1]]
    counts = []
    for m in [emb_dim, emb_dim + 1]:
        counts.append(0)
        # get the matrix that we need for the current m
        tVecsM = tVecs[:n - m + 1, :m]
        # successively calculate distances between each pair of template vectors
        for i in range(len(tVecsM)):
            dsts = dist(tVecsM, tVecsM[i])
            # delete self-matching
            dsts = np.delete(dsts, i, axis=0)
            # delete undefined distances coming from zero segments
            # dsts = [x for i, x in enumerate(dsts) if not np.isnan(x) and not np.isinf(x)]
            # count how many 'defined' distances are smaller than the tolerance
            # if (dsts):
            counts[-1] += np.sum(dsts < tolerance)/(n - m - 1)

    if counts[1] == 0:
        # log would be infinite => cannot determine RangeEn_B
        RangeEn_B = np.nan
    else:
        # compute log of summed probabilities
        RangeEn_B = -np.log(1.0 * counts[1] / counts[0])

    return RangeEn_B
```

My attempt is below:

```
w=np.apply_along_axis(RangeEn_B, 1, rolling_window(rs_num,5 , 1))
```

although this returns an array of nan, if I put 30 it returns values.

Am i correct in my logic?

I also tried to do in pandas as well -

```
#Assume matrix is a series
t = pd.Series(rs_num)
t=t.rolling(window=5, min_periods=2).apply(RangeEn_B).dropna()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the function dist_range? Otherwise your code is not reproducible.

Comment: I generally discourage using `apply_along_axis` - unless the array 3d or higher.  It can simplify iterating over 2 of 3 dimensions, but is of little value when the input is only 2d.  It's hard to tell, just by reading, what's the shape of the `rolling_window(...)`.

Comment: Cheers all I have uploaded the code with dist range.